# How long can a Spotify Session be refreshed

Tags: spotify

Refresh of Spotify Session works fine.
But how long can a spotify be refreshed?

So yesterday I refreshed a session that was 15 minutes above the expiration date and it works. So today I try to refresh this session again and get an error code 400.

Comment: Are you talking about the Web API? The question looks a bit incomplete.

Comment: Like @JMPerez says, this question feels very incomplete. If you're asking about how long a refresh token is valid, it's pretty much forever.